# Kommasetzung bei vergleichendem »als«

Tags: punctuation, comma, comparison

In Deutsch gilt normalerweise die Regel, dass Phrasen, die ein Verb enthalten, durch Komma abgetrennt werden. 
Die Konjunktion *als* kann sowohl temporär als auch für Vergleiche verwendet werden.

> Als ich das Fenster aufmachte, merkte ich, wie warm es ist.
>   Ich bin größer als Klaus.

Man kann mit *als* auch Aktionen vergleichen.

> Ich kann schneller schreiben, als Thomas reden kann.

Hier nun ein Beispiel in der Vergangenheit:

> Ich habe schneller geschrieben, als Thomas geredet hat.

Das kann zwei Sachen heißen:

- mein Schreibtempo > Thomas’ Redetempo
- mein Schreibtempo, wenn Thomas redet > mein Tempo, wenn er nicht redet.

Ich würde hier dazu tendieren, im ersten Fall, also beim Vergleich, das Komma wegzulassen, da ich finde, dass es eine zu starke Trennung verursacht.
Meine Frage ist: **Ist das Komma bei vergleichendem *als* mit zwei Prädikaten wirklich zwingend?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, das Komma ist zwingend. Ich zitiere aus den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln:

> **§ 74** Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so
>   schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.
>
> […]
>
> *Sie sah gesünder aus, als sie sich fühlte.*

Dieses Beispiel bestätigt, dass derartige Konstrukte mit *als* wie alle anderen Nebensätze behandelt werden.

Weiter heißt es:

> E3: Vergleiche mit *als* oder *wie* in Verbindung mit einer Wortgruppe oder
>   einem Wort sind keine Nebensätze; entsprechend setzt man kein Komma […]:
>   *Früher als gewöhnlich kam er von der Arbeit nach Hause. […]*

Aus dieser Formulierung wird zwar nicht ganz klar, dass *Wortgruppe* derartige Konstrukte ausschließt (immerhin ist so ziemlich alles eine Wortgruppe, insbesondere auch ein Nebensatz), aber in keinem der Beispiele enthält diese Wortgruppe ein konjugiertes Verb.